# Ec2-user suddenly not working after aborting

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, server, key, putty

My username and password for the instance is the same. Infact i dont even know if i can change the ppk key or the username. I was had gained root access and was adding ssl to my ec2 instance. I happen to abort the connection and tried connecting it back and it shows **Server refused our key.**
Before aborting my previous connection, i happen to add the folder **certs** into my **etc** folder as mentioned in the docs for adding third party ssl. Now im not able to login to my ec2
What did i do wrong? Im sure the key is right as i had multiple copies stored in different places and i tried them all

Comment: Please move your question to [Super User](https://superuser.com/) (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

I realised that i had accidentally deleted the etc folder in the instance. I had to create a new one. Instead of deleting a folder inside etc, i had deleted the folder etc itself.